# Checking positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, spectral-radius

Is the matrix $(A - D^{T}AD)$ positive definite if the spectral radius of $D$, $\rho(D)<1$? Here $A$ is a positive definite matrix and $D^{T}$ denotes the transpose of $D$.  $A$ and $D$ are both real matrices.

My intuition says so but I am not being able to prove rigorously. One can assume $D^{T}AD = DAD^{T}$, if necessary.

Comment: Can you please be more specific and say if the matrices you are considering are real or complex? Plus, what is D'? Is it connected to the matrix D, or is it completely arbitrary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.
$$
\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&1}-\pmatrix{1\\ &0}\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&1}\pmatrix{1\\ &0}
=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&1}
$$
is indefinite. So, if we replace $\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$ by $\operatorname{diag}(1-\epsilon,0)$ for some sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, the result is indefinite too.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, not in general. Indeed, take $A=I$. So, $((I- D^t D)x, x)=(x,x)-(Dx, Dx)$. This can be less than $0$, even if $D$ is nilpotent.
.................................................................

THIS IS WRONG:

However, if moreover  $D^t A D= DAD^t$, that means $D$ is normal for the inner product $(x,y)_A\colon =(Ax,y)$. $\ \ \rho(D)<1$ implies $(Dx,Dx)_A< (x,x)_A$ for all $x\ne 0$, which is equivalent to $A- D^t AD$ positive definite.

.................................................................

CORRECTED: No, it does not mean $D$ is normal for that inner product. In fact, the conjugate of $D$ is $A^{-1}D^tA$, so the normality condition is 
$$DA^{-1}D^tA = A^{-1}D^tA D$$

Comment: @user1551: yes, you are totally right,  thanks for letting me know. I will write the correct conjugate of $D$ under the inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)_A$.